# TypeError: address_finder() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given result for a Flask Webapp

Tags: python, html, flask

Trying to create a quick little project where I have an HTML page that will allow the User to input a value and on the next page, it should return a key in a dictionary I have created. However, after entering the value- here is what I get
`TypeError: address_finder() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given`

Here is my python file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

location = {"673 Ayres Ave":["acs building", "ACS building", "BLDG 750", "Soldier Support     Center", "soldier support center"],
"BLDG 683": ["Desmond Doss Health Clinic", "Desmond Doss", "desmond doss", "desmond doss   health clinic"], 
"694 McCornack Rd":["PX", "Schofield Main Exchange", "Post Exchange", "px", "post exchange",  "schofield main exchange"]}

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/directions", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def address_finder():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_input = request.form['location']
        result = address_finder(location, user_input.lower())

        if result != user_input:
            return f"The location for '{user_input}' is: {result}"
        else:
            return f"'{user_input}' not found in the dictionary"
    return render_template('inputpage.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is my HTML template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>Address Finder</title>
  </head>
   <body>
     <h1>Address Finder</h1>
     <form method="POST">
         <label for="location">Enter the location you want to find:</label>
         <input type="text" name="location" id="location">
         <input type="submit" value="Find Address">
     </form>
   </body>
  </html>
```

I have tried to put two arguments in the address_finder function, but when I do that, I lose my first page on the HTML site to another type error

Comment: you have `result = address_finder(location, user_input.lower())` but the function doesn't take any arguments. Why are you calling the function inside itself, anyway? This will cause infinite recursion.

Comment: `def address_finder()` This defines the function to take no arguments, yet you try to pass two arguments when you call it.  Why?